# Flash message display grails

Tags: grails, gsp

Can I do something like this inside controller action

```
def update(){

    if(certain validation fails )
    //flash message to be visible 
    [domainInstance:originalDomainInstance,flash.message : "message(code:'default.some.code.label', default:'Please provide your validation err msg.' )"]
}
```

The above throws syntax error.
I am still trying to fix the syntax. Is it alrite to send the flash message in this way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails controller returns model which is in simple case just map (map with `domainInstance` in your case). `flash` is property which is available in controllers.

```
def update(){

    if(certain validation fails ) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.some.code.label', default: 'Please provide your validation err msg.')
    }

    [domainInstance: originalDomainInstance]
}
```

If you would to pass message in model map the syntax should look like below:

```
[domainInstance: originalDomainInstance, myMessage: message(code: 'default.some.code.label', default: 'Please provide your validation err msg.')]
```

Useful links: [flash](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.9/ref/Controllers/flash.html) and [models and views in Grails](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#modelsAndViews).

Comment: Thanks Pawel. It works. But is it ok to pass the flash.message inside the [.....flash.message : "message(code:'default.some.code.label', default:'Please provide your validation err msg.' )"]? I was trying to pass as regular string message.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get what exactly would you like to do. Do you want to pass some message in model map?

Comment: Yes inside model map ,can I pass flash.message ?Well this question is out of curiosity. And I have already implemented your approach.

Comment: You can pass message but the name should be different than `flash.message`. Take a look at updated answer.

Comment: No problem. Happy coding with Grails :)